# jQuery AJAX POST to PHP issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I’m trying to evaluate the value of `id`, which should be passed in the POST from jQuery to PHP.

The call is returning `{'id':'99'}`, which is ok if `id` is not equal to 0. I wonder why `($x == "0")` is not being evaluated to `true` in my PHP function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/more.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"id" : "0"}),
        success: function(data) {
            $("body").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","schema");
        getmore($_POST['id']);

        function getmore($x) {
         if ($x == "0") {
          $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM IRCLOG WHERE DATETIME >= date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day)");
         }
         else {
          $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM IRCLOG WHERE DATETIME >= date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day)");
         }
           // your business logic
          $rows = array();
          while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
             $rows[] = $r;
          }

          echo json_encode($rows);
        }
    }
else {echo "{'id':'99'}";}
```

Comment: what value you get when you echo $x?

Comment: did you try if (is_numeric($x) && $x === 0)) or compare 0 without  "(quotes)

Comment: function getmore  defined inside if ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be because PHP is converting the `$_POST['id']` to integer. Try the following:

```
function getmore($x) {
    $x = intval( $x );
    if ($x == 0) {
```

---

Another reason might be that your AJAX is sending the data incorrectly. Try using:

```
data: {id : "0"}
```

in the AJAX request.

The `data` setting in AJAX call accepts either `PlainObject` or `String` argument. From the docs:

> It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's
>   appended to the url for GET-requests. See `processData` option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var id_main = 0;
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/more.php",
            data: { id: id_main },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

send your data like this.
data: {"id" : "0"},